# get values of date-input-boxes from rangeSelector

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to get the values of the date-input-boxes from rangeSelector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can get these values.  If you are using JQuery:

```
var minDate = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(0)').val();
var maxDate = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(1)').val();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have another question about the input field. Is it possible to add a click event to the inputfield?

Comment: Add a click event like this: $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(0)').click(function() {  // your code here });

Comment: I am trying to do something like `$('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(0)').live('change', function(){ zoomStartEpochTime = this.value; });` but it says `TypeError: $(...).live is not a function`

Comment: I also tried `.on`  as `$('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(0)').on('change', function(){ zoomStartEpochTime = this.value; });` as I am using jquery 1.11

Answer (score 6):

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(chartingOptions);
...
var zoomStartEpochTime = chart.rangeSelector.leftBox.HCTime;
var zoomEndEpochTime = chart.rangeSelector.rightBox.HCTime;
```

Alternatively you can [query the xAxis's extreme values](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.getExtremes%28%29) for the same

```
var zoomStartEpochTime = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min;
var zoomEndEpochTime = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max;
```

Comment: Much preferred answer using the extreme values in this instance.