# Save value from RangeSelector's 'From' 'To' fields using highcharts

Tags: highcharts, angular7

I want to save date values from 'From' and 'To' fields using Highchart's RangeSelector. 
[my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8lmG.png). i have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269678/get-values-of-date-input-boxes-from-rangeselector) thread but didn't know how\where to use getExtreme()..

I am new to angular and using charts for first time. i will really appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

`getExtremes()` method can be called on xAxis instance to get a current `min` and `max` from the chart. It can be used in `xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes` callback, so that every change in the chart extremes will be caught. Check the example posted below with `highcharts-angular` official wrapper that I encourage you to use (can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular)

**Code:**

```
   xAxis: {
      events: {
        afterSetExtremes: (function(self) {
          return function() {
            const chart = this.chart;

            self.rangeSelectorFrom = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min;
            self.rangeSelectorTo = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max;
          };
        })(this)
      }
    }
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-0fw7q

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes